# Потоки в java, синхронизация данных

Tags: java, многопоточность, map, map-reduce

Пишу программу для подсчёта слов в текстовом файле. Проблема заключается в том что, при выполнении программы в итоге выводит 0 уникальных слов (или какое-то число не превышающее 5000 тысяч). Не могу понять в чем проблема.
В качестве текстового файла взял "Войну и мир" (для увеличения символов, откопировал её 5 раз).

Код:

```
static int i =0;
static Map<String, Integer> mainMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String PathToFile = "D:\\WarAndPeace1.txt";
    ArrayList<String> wordsTemp = new ArrayList<String>();


    try {
        File file = new File(PathToFile);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            i++;
            if (wordsTemp.size()<=500000) {
                String FinalWord = convertedWord(scanner.next().toLowerCase());
                if (!FinalWord.equals("")||FinalWord!=null)
                wordsTemp.add(FinalWord);
            }
            else{
                Runnable r = new NewThread(wordsTemp);
                new Thread(r).start();

                wordsTemp.clear();
                wordsTemp.add(scanner.next().toLowerCase());
            }
        }
        scanner.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : mainMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":"
                + e.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println("Уникальных слов: "+mainMap.size());
    System.out.println("Всего слов: "+i);
    long timeSpent = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println("программа выполнялась " + timeSpent + " миллисекунд");

}

// Создание второго потока
static class NewThread implements Runnable {

    Thread thread;
    //Map<String, Integer> map;
    ArrayList <String> strings;
    // Конструктор
    NewThread(ArrayList <String> strings) {
        // Создаём новый второй поток          
        this.strings = strings;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Поток для примера");
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        Map<String, Integer> mTempMap = wordCount(strings, mainMap);
        synchronized (this) {
            mainMap = mTempMap;
        }
    }
}
public static Map<String, Integer> wordCount( ArrayList <String> strings, Map<String, Integer> map) {
    Map<String, Integer> mapTemp = map;
    String s;
    for (int i = 0;strings.size()>i;i++){
        s = strings.get(i);
        if (s!=null) {
            if (!map.containsKey(s)) {  // first time we've seen this string
                map.put(s, 1);
            } else {
                int count = map.get(s);
                map.put(s, count + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}

//Преобразование
public static String convertedWord (String word){
    String result = word.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");//регулярным выражением заменяем буквы(\\w) и цифры(\\d) на пустую строку, то есть удаляем.
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Как вы думаете, что происходит с `NewThread.strings` после вызова `wordsTemp.clear();`?

Comment: верно заметил коллега выше. похоже, что очищаете объект по  ссылке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишу несколько вопросов-замечаний:

1. Как вы думаете, что происходит с `NewThread.strings` после вызова `wordsTemp.clear();`? И что произойдет, если заменить его на `wordsTemp = new ArrayList<String>();`?
2. Метод `wordCount()` может выдавать некорректные результаты, поскольку код внутри условия `if (s!=null)` не является атомарным и не синхронизирован. Например, если три потока придут на этот участок кода для одинакового слова, то после завершения выполнения этого участка в мапе может лежать не `count + 3`, а всего лишь `count + 1`:

   ```
   int count = map.get(s);
   map.put(s, count + 1);
   ```

   Лучше воспользоваться методом [`compute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-).
3. `synchronized` вокруг присваивания ссылки не нужен -- эта операция и так атомарная. Да и само присваивание не нужно -- см. след. пункт.
4. Не запутывайте сами себя в методе `wordCount()`. Вы принимаете мапу, присваиваете ее неиспользуемой переменной, модифицируете ее, возвращаете ее же, а потом переприсваиваете. Просто модифицируйте и все. Почистите код (весь), глядишь и ошибки искать будет легче.

Comment: Спасибо, с ходу помог первый пункт(вопрос-замечание).

Comment: @EgorChetvernin пожалуйста.